# MAMP | localhost:8888 | two sites using Coda 2

Tags: mysql, localhost, mamp, coda

I freely admit I must have made an error setting up my first site on MAMP, but I can't find it anywhere.

For some time, I have had a PHP/AJAX site called Tag drawing data from a local database via MAMP. The files are all in a folder called Tag which is located within MAMP's htdocs folder. Yet when I connect to the files via my browser, I type in http://localhost:8888/tag.php and not http://localhost:8888/Tag/tag.php.

Now I would like a second site called finances to run off my local DB and server. I've set up a folder in MAMP's htdocs as before, called /finances/. And I've specified my site in the same way (using Coda 2) as I specified Tag, i.e. setting the Remote URL as http://localhost:8888/finances instead of http://localhost:8888/Tag and setting the local root for convenience of folders/files (that part works fine).

Now neither Coda nor my browser can find anything like http://localhost:8888/finances.php or http://localhost:8888/finances/finances.php. It's because the definition of http://localhost:8888/ seems to include the folder Tag. But how did I do this? And how do I undo it?

I've looked through all the settings I can think of. If anyone knows please help!

Thanks

Emma

Answer (score 0):

MAMP > preferences > Document root was the answer here. I still haven't got Coda to cope with two localhost sites but at least I know why it was defaulting to a particular folder.